# Custom styles on inputs with angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I am trying to style an input so that it is a certain width. I am using Angular Material 2 but for some reason the styles in the css isn't being applied to the input tag. [Here is a working plunker of my issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/qHbyig0gHtxdquRL63vI?p=preview) along with the affected code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <form>
      <md-input [(ngModel)]="cycleTime" type="number" name="email">
        <span md-prefix>Cycle Time:</span>
        <span md-suffix>&nbsp;minutes</span>
      </md-input>
    </form>
  </div>
  `,
  styles:[`
      input {
        width: 50px;
        text-align: right;
      }
    `],
  directives: [MdButton, MdInput]
})
export class AppComponent { 
  cycleTime = 1

  constructor() {}
}
```

How can I style the input that is being created by Angular Material 2?

Comment: PLease help me resolve my query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691754/angular-ag-grid-attach-class-to-grouped-rows-cell-based-on-validation-of-other-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to override styles of `MdInput` component like this:

```
:host input.md-input-element {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yVcuHuRJASEBj1YwVd1c?p=preview)

Or this way:

```
/deep/ input {
  width: 50px !important;
  text-align: right;
}

:host-context .md-input-infix input {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: This solution effects all inputs. Is there a way to do it for only one input or a group of input?

Comment: @hayzum ::ng-deep .myinput {}