# Is there a way to change style of a md-input?

Tags: html, css, angular, input, angular-material

I have a form with `md-input`s. First input for user id, i wanna transform the input to uppercase. I've tried to assign `style="text-transformation:uppercase;"`, it transformed placeholder text.

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38444373/1554947 , however this one effects all inputs.

I'm very new with Angular. I've tried to assign `class` or `id` to the input but didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to transform the input to uppercase while user is typing?

Comment: @developer033 yes, I do.

Comment: It's working in this [**`PLUNKER`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9pp8MKuHzWqQzw0eLzyO?p=preview).

Comment: @developer033 I'm using Angular 2, `md-input-container` doesn't work.

Comment: If you mean overriding some existing style for a single component, you can consider using `/deep/` css tag that will catch that for you.
Example : `/deep/ .md-select-value {
    height: 100%;
}`